# Browsers are slow

Tags: performance, browser

I have just bought a new (but cheap) laptop, Processor  2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz and RAM 4GB and it takes about 5 to 10 seconds to open an average page in Firefox and Chromium. Is this normal?

Other applications are not extremely fast either, but browsers are really slow. My internet is fast.

EDIT:
Here's my [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sZdJgQyu) of `lspci -nnk`

Internet speed:

> PING 6 ms  DOWNLOAD
>   28.96 Mbps  UPLOAD
>   15.51 Mbps
>
> SCSI Disks ATA SanDisk SD8SBAT1
>
> Operating System Version Kernel    Linux 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64) Compiled   #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 5.4.0
>   20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
>
> Distribution   Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>
> Computer Name asus-E502SA

EDIT 2: sudo lshw -C disk

> ```
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: SanDisk SD8SBAT1
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sda
>    version: 7002
>    serial: 165385403049
>    size: 119GiB (128GB)
>    capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=b99c18cd
> ```

EDIT 3: 
https://pastebin.com/wSbiTBKc  for

> sudo lshw -C memory

Comment: This is probably not about Ubuntu, voting to close.

Comment: I am a computers near illiterate. I have just installed Ubuntu and noticed how slow browsers are and I want to know why. Is this due to hardware or software? As I run Ubuntu, I thought asking here appropriate.

Comment: Well, why haven't you mentioned Ubuntu in the question? Most cheap notebooks are sold with Windows, which is even safer bet if an Ubuntu version is not mentioned. Anyway, you should add the output of `lspci -nnk` to the question, also, add info about internet connection and speed, and about the laptop make and model. Then, hopefully, we can start working. As is, the question is vague and subjective.

Comment: if you have a normal HDD and not an SSD this isn't unreasonable imo.

Comment: @mikewhatever since OP says they are "near [computer] illiterate" maybe you could be a little more specific about some of the additional info you'd need to answer this? How can they add specific details about internet connection & speed? I don't know myself, or I would comment accordingly

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I edited my question as requested by @mikewhatever - I thought it was too obvious I run Ubuntu!

Comment: hmmm... I opened http://pasebin.com/ and have no idea what to do there??

Comment: It's http://pastebin.com, sorry about the typo. You just copy/paste text into the text field, hopefully, the formatting will be more presentable.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sZdJgQyu

Comment: Checking the specs on the Asus model you provided I could use just a bit more clarity. Would you be so kind as to [edit] into your post the output of `sudo lshw -C disk` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: So, the specs are ok, and internet speed/connection is quite decent. Unless there are problems we can find, I'd say, the hardware is no speed demon. It works, but is rather slow, which should be expected.

Comment: @mikewhatever  You mean 1.60GHz processor, which I suppose is rather weak, is the main culprit for slow browsers?

Comment: @b16108 That's part of it, but I suspect memory speed is also a factor. The output of `sudo lshw -C memory` should make everything clear.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wSbiTBKc  for

sudo lshw -C memory

Comment: @b16108 Actually, I wouldn't say that hardware/CPU is too slow. It should be ok for web browsing, however, depending on expectations and the point of comparison, it may be deemed slow or fast. Obviously, there are faster machines, and if that's what you compare to, it's slow. On the other hand, compare it to RaspberryPi3, and it's going to be really fast. As a practical step to speed up web page loading, I'd recommend an add blocker like ublock or Adblockplus for Firefox, as well as whatever people use for Chrome.

Comment: 1) @mikewhatever: i definitely recommend [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/), it is much lighter on resources and available for different browsers. **||** 2) maybe a lightweight browser like `midori` or `netsurf` (attention: netsurf is not HTML5-compliant and rudimentary JavaScript-support has just been added in version 3.4) can speed things a little bit up...!

Comment: Thank you guys for all your insight! I added Adblockplus on Chromium and uBlock on Firefox. The performance is slightly better now. Now I will try  also uBlock Origin. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

These little netbooks are painfully slow browsing the web. It has a SSD which is good, but the CPU is no speed demon and a single bank of DDR3 RAM at 1400 MHz doesn't do you any favors either.

To help explain it might help to know that DDR stands for Double Data Rate. This gives the impression of higher speed but it requires 2 matched sticks in 2 banks to achieve the "Double Data Rate".

Sadly many major manufacturers tout the benefits of DDR RAM in their advertising copy without mentioning that their designs use only a single stick (eliminating any benefit)

Edit: If [this](http://www.how-fixit.com/laptop-repair-guides/asus-laptop/asus-eeebook-e502/) is your model it appears that the RAM is soldered to the mainboard  north of the fan and east of the battery (with the fan in the loweer right hand corner. It's not possible to upgrade it. This is further confirmed by Asus not listing RAM as available as [spare parts for the E502SA.](https://en.accessoires-asus.com/laptop/e502/e502sa/e502sa-65451-59173.htm) Even [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for//e502sa) is strangely silent on this topic.

Comment: I researched the web about what you said. The only thing now is to find out if I have a second slot for RAM. Thanks!